# Delphi Seattle has very big font as default

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10-seattle

Delphi Seattle has very big font as default , and I dont like it.

tried to change it as I did with XE8 with a script

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\ModernTheme]

     "FontName"="Segoe UI"

     "FontSize"=dword:0000000a

     "MainToolBarColor"="clGradientActiveCaption"
```

But it did not work , how is this handled in Delphi Seattle ?

[image]

Comment: So it's the font in the tool palette that you are concerned with.

Comment: I can't find anything changed in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/System_Registry_Keys_for_IDE_Visual_Settings). By the look of it, it seems you are setting the default values.

Comment: David it's not only the tool palette, its also the project pane ++  , but as I said in my post in XE8 you could run a script as descriped in my post to reset all IDE fonts to  f.eks 10..

Comment: I pasted the script from your link LU RD , and now it worked Thanks

Comment: From the docs: *The default is 10*. So yes, you have just reassigned the default value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/System_Registry_Keys_for_IDE_Visual_Settings) has not changed between the two versions.

> **Creating a Registry Script File**
>
> 1. Create a new text document (you can use any text editor) and copy the following text into it:
>
>    ```
>    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
>    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\ModernTheme]
>    "FontName"="Segoe UI"
>    "FontSize"=dword:0000000a
>    "MainToolBarColor"="clGradientActiveCaption"
>    ```
>
>    **Note:** See the table of customizable values for details about the specified values.
> 2. Save the document with the .reg extension.
> 3. Execute the registry script file that you created. A warning about changing the registry may appear. You must accept it in order to apply the changes.
>
>    **Note:** You may need Administrator permissions to be able to execute registry script files. If the IDE is open when you set or change registry values, you must restart the IDE for the values to take effect.

The default values for the font appearance are as shown above, and it seems you are just reassigning them.