# Delphi 10 Seattle options font size too big

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have started using Delphi 10. Everything is working fine except for the font which doesn't resize to the proper screen resolution. It is a screenshot of when I select from the menu bar > Tools > Options.
[image: screenshot]

It's the same with Menu bar > Projects > Options.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks like an installation issue. Have you tried opening a free installation related help ticket via [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com) to see if they can help? There's not much anyone here can do, other than say try using the default font size in your system settings to see if that helps. It looks like an issue with high DPI settings on Windows 10 to me. Seattle doesn't have support for high DPI; Berlin does.

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/q/32392773/576719.

Comment: See here for a fix: [ID: 30367, <Update3>A temporary fix (imperfect) for Large Fonts R10](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30367).

Comment: It is a bug in Delphi see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11824

Comment: I did tried installing on another computer and the font size is fine. So I did suspect that it is difference in font installed in different computer. I am using Wiindows 7 on Dell XPS and the other computer is also Windows 7 on HP Elite 600.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you want to tell someone their answer worked, accept it by clicking the checkmark below the counter at the upper left of their answer. If you feel the answer was worth it, you can also upvote it by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Embarcadero documentation has [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/System_Registry_Keys_for_IDE_Visual_Settings) link as a fix.

Creating a Registry Script File

> Create a new text document (you can use any text editor) and copy the
>   following text into it:
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\18.0\ModernTheme] 
> "FontName"="Segoe UI" 
> "FontSize"=dword:0000000a 
> "MainToolBarColor"="clGradientActiveCaption"
> ```
>
> Note: See the table of customizable values for details about the
>   specified values. Save the document with the .reg extension. Execute
>   the registry script file that you created.
>
> A warning about changing the registry may appear. You must accept it
>   in order to apply the changes.
>
> Note: You may need Administrator permissions to be able to execute
>   registry script files. If the IDE is open when you set or change
>   registry values, you must restart the IDE for the values to take
>   effect.

Comment: And then use microscope? ;-)

Comment: I did tried this script file but doesn't work. I did tried installing on another computer and I don't get the same problem with font size. So I am going to tried @Tom Brunberg suggestion because I did customize my font size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have selected "Larger - 150%" in your display settings (`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display`) and also ticked "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" in the compatibility settings for Delphi 10 Seattle. Revert either or both settings.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works. It works now when the font set to default to 100%. But now everything is real small. Thanks again.

Comment: You should select this answer as the correct one since it provided you a solution. Whoever put -1 on this should learn that he is wrong.